# Android: Using HID over GATT directly in Application (Gadget=HID → control Application)

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, hid

I have a Bluetooth LE Joystick with a couple of buttons. I want to connect it directly to the app without using the Bluetooth Settings, but by connecting to it via `BluetoothLeScanner`.

I already can connect to a Heart Rate Monitor and get periodic notifications of the HR-values.

I also have created a little temperature/light/humidity sensor with an ESP32 to which I can also connnect and display the sensor values in the app.

My understanding of this HID device may be erroneous. With the help of the App BLE Scanner I can connect to this gadget via BLE and see the offered services.

One of them is `0x1812 HUMAN INTERFACE DEVICE`, which contains a couple of characteristics of type `REPORT`, among others which are described `HID OVER GATT PROFILE SPECIFICATION` (`HOGP_SPEC`)

How can I find out which button got pressed, what position the joystick has been moved to? I guess that this has to occur via notifications to which I have to subscribe to.

Is there any Android library avaliable to handle HID input devices? What I do NOT want to do is to use the Bluetooth settings and connect to the device and have it become detected as a HID device and replace the keyboard with some odd mapping. I don't want the OS to get involved at all, just like when I connect and use the HRM and the ESP32.

I couldn't find any information on this.

I can connect to the device with my app, enumerate the services and characteristics. But from there on, I have no clue how to work with HID. Ideally I'd get notifications like "Button A has been pressed" "Joystick got moved to x=32" where x would range from -127 to 127, for example.

Comment: For what it's worth, a friend had a stroke and is now mostly unable to talk. I'm looking forward to create an app which can be easily controlled by a $10 multi-button / joystick BLE device. Would be open sourced.

Comment: Great work Daniel, Does device pass any kind of acknowledgement when button press

Comment: No. Upon connecting I do "subscribe" to the notifications of the Report Characteristic in the `onServicesDiscovered`. But I never receive anything else from the device, `onCharacteristicChanged` is not called upon a button press. I'm reading through https://github.com/kshoji/BLE-HID-Peripheral-for-Android/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/jp/kshoji/blehid/HidPeripheral.java in order to try to understand how a HID device behaves. Maybe I need to bind to it somehow.

Comment: You maybe should do a GATT server connection? Maybe the next answer should help you a bite: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55680180/unable-to-read-data-via-bluetooth-successfully/56056273#56056273

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing the HID characteristics requires the BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED permission since Android 5.0. The only way for an app to obtain that permission is to be signed with the same certificates as system apps.

This is a security feature, to prevent an app from receiving HID events from your keyboard and stealing your passwords.

Quoting from https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/cfs-file/__key/communityserver-discussions-components-files/4/BLE_5F00_on_5F00_Android_5F00_v1.0.1.pdf

> 4.6  Protected services
>
> Android does not allow to read or write data to the following characteristics (and their descriptors):
>
> 1. HID Service (since Android 5):
>
> ```
> a.  HID Information
> b.  Report Map
> c.  HID Control Point
> d.  Report
> ```
>
> 2. FIDO (https://fidoalliance.org/) (since Android 6)
>
> ```
> a.  U2F (0000FFFD-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB)
> ```
>
> Only applications with BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED, that is, applications signed
> with the same certificate as the system,    are able to read and write
> data to those characteristics.